# R Start and stop station columns can not be the same. When this is the case, select the start/stop from the nearest correct observation (row)

Tags: r, time-series

I have this problem that I have been trying to solve. I have this dataframe where there is a index id, timestamp, start_station, stop_station and an indicator whether start_station = stop_station. It is time series data so I have arranged it on the timestamp variable. The data looks like this:

```
          id timestamp           start_station stop_station  same_start_stop
   <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>         <chr>                   <dbl>
 1    82 2023-05-04 18:59:29 Sandvika      Asker                       0
 2    83 2023-05-04 19:00:45 Sandvika      Asker                       0
 3    84 2023-05-04 19:01:17 Sandvika      Asker                       0
 4    85 2023-05-05 07:15:06 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0
 5    86 2023-05-05 07:20:12 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1
 6    87 2023-05-05 07:24:56 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0
 7    88 2023-05-05 07:25:11 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0
 8    89 2023-05-05 07:25:15 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1
 9    90 2023-05-05 07:25:30 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1
10    91 2023-05-05 07:25:34 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0
11    92 2023-05-05 07:25:51 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1
12    93 2023-05-05 07:26:10 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1
13   215 2023-05-05 08:11:06 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0
14   216 2023-05-05 08:12:46 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0
15   217 2023-05-05 08:14:14 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1
16   218 2023-05-05 08:15:23 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0
17   219 2023-05-05 08:16:06 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0
18   443 2023-05-05 11:40:34 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0
19   444 2023-05-05 11:40:37 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0
20   445 2023-05-05 11:42:56 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0
21   446 2023-05-05 11:44:56 Lillestrøm    Lillestrøm                  1
22   447 2023-05-05 11:46:00 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0
23   448 2023-05-05 11:46:08 Lillestrøm    Lillestrøm                  1
24   449 2023-05-05 11:46:10 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0
25   858 2023-05-06 18:10:14 Kolbotn       Lørenskog                   0
26   859 2023-05-07 12:17:44 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0
27   860 2023-05-07 12:23:08 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1
28   861 2023-05-07 12:25:54 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0
29   862 2023-05-07 12:25:59 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1
30   863 2023-05-07 12:26:00 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0
```

I have taken a subset of the data. Normally the timestamps will be a lot closer. I have about 5 k rows. So the issue is, it is not supposed to be possible to have start_station = stop_station. Therefore, I have created this indicator. What I now want, is I want to:

Where start_stop == 1, take the nearest row value of start_station and stop_station where start_stop == 0 and update the existing start_station and stop_station with the values where start_stop == 0. Does it make sense?

The desired outcome is this:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 7
      id timestamp           start_station stop_station  same_start_stop new_start     new_end      
   <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>         <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        
 1    82 2023-05-04 18:59:29 Sandvika      Asker                       0 NA            NA           
 2    83 2023-05-04 19:00:45 Sandvika      Asker                       0 NA            NA           
 3    84 2023-05-04 19:01:17 Sandvika      Asker                       0 NA            NA           
 4    85 2023-05-05 07:15:06 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0 NA            NA           
 5    86 2023-05-05 07:20:12 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn
 6    87 2023-05-05 07:24:56 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0 NA            NA           
 7    88 2023-05-05 07:25:11 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0 NA            NA           
 8    89 2023-05-05 07:25:15 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn
 9    90 2023-05-05 07:25:30 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn
10    91 2023-05-05 07:25:34 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn               0 NA            NA           
11    92 2023-05-05 07:25:51 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn
12    93 2023-05-05 07:26:10 Oslo lufthavn Oslo lufthavn               1 Oslo S        Oslo lufthavn
13   215 2023-05-05 08:11:06 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0 NA            NA           
14   216 2023-05-05 08:12:46 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0 NA            NA           
15   217 2023-05-05 08:14:14 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S       
16   218 2023-05-05 08:15:23 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0 NA            NA           
17   219 2023-05-05 08:16:06 Oslo lufthavn Oslo S                      0 NA            NA           
18   443 2023-05-05 11:40:34 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0 NA            NA           
19   444 2023-05-05 11:40:37 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0 NA            NA           
20   445 2023-05-05 11:42:56 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0 NA            NA           
21   446 2023-05-05 11:44:56 Lillestrøm    Lillestrøm                  1 Oslo S        Eidsvoll     
22   447 2023-05-05 11:46:00 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0 NA            NA           
23   448 2023-05-05 11:46:08 Lillestrøm    Lillestrøm                  1 Oslo S        Eidsvoll     
24   449 2023-05-05 11:46:10 Oslo S        Eidsvoll                    0 NA            NA           
25   858 2023-05-06 18:10:14 Kolbotn       Lørenskog                   0 NA            NA           
26   859 2023-05-07 12:17:44 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0 NA            NA           
27   860 2023-05-07 12:23:08 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1 Oslo S        Lillestrøm   
28   861 2023-05-07 12:25:54 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0 NA            NA           
29   862 2023-05-07 12:25:59 Oslo S        Oslo S                      1 Oslo S        Lillestrøm   
30   863 2023-05-07 12:26:00 Oslo S        Lillestrøm                  0 NA            NA
```

I simply can not figure out how to do it properly. Sometimes several wrong ones come in order, so I can not simply do a lead and lag (I think). Additionally, sometimes by taking the row underneath it could be wrong. For instance, if id = 219 in the data below, if the script just took the combination below (Oslo S & Eidsvoll) it would be wrong. However, I know this last bit might be a lot trickier, so if one can not solve this, I would just look through these "neighbour" cases manually.

Thanks for the help. I am open for tidyverse, base R or data.table, whichever works

This is the structure of the data:

```
structure(list(id = c(82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
92, 93, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 
449, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863), timestamp = structure(c(1683226769, 
1683226845, 1683226877, 1683270906, 1683271212, 1683271496, 1683271511, 
1683271515, 1683271530, 1683271534, 1683271551, 1683271570, 1683274266, 
1683274366, 1683274454, 1683274523, 1683274566, 1683286834, 1683286837, 
1683286976, 1683287096, 1683287160, 1683287168, 1683287170, 1683396614, 
1683461864, 1683462188, 1683462354, 1683462359, 1683462360), label = "Actual Survey Start Time", tzone = "UTC", format.spss = "DATETIME20", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), start_station = structure(c("Sandvika", "Sandvika", 
"Sandvika", "Oslo S", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo lufthavn", 
"Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo S", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", 
"Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo S", "Oslo lufthavn", 
"Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Lillestrøm", 
"Oslo S", "Lillestrøm", "Oslo S", "Kolbotn", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", 
"Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo S"), format.spss = "A50", display_width = 50L), 
    stop_station = structure(c("Asker", "Asker", "Asker", "Oslo lufthavn", 
    "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", 
    "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", "Oslo lufthavn", 
    "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Oslo S", "Eidsvoll", 
    "Eidsvoll", "Eidsvoll", "Lillestrøm", "Eidsvoll", "Lillestrøm", 
    "Eidsvoll", "Lørenskog", "Lillestrøm", "Oslo S", "Lillestrøm", 
    "Oslo S", "Lillestrøm"), format.spss = "A50", display_width = 50L), 
    same_start_stop = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```